# How to start a sudo-privilage program with screen so that I can re-attach to it later?

Tags: debian, bash, sudo, root

Here's the problem I face: I have a program that must run as root. I want that to run in a screen, but here's a twist: for admin reasons, I want to be able to re-attach to it.

I'm writing a dirty and fast restarter daemon, because the program keeps on failing in very misterious ways, that is running as sudo (because I need root priv. to start the app). However I don't want to simply run screen as sudo, because then `screen -ls` won't show it, only `sudo screen -ls`. If I run `sudo -u USER screen -dmS SCREEN_NAME sudo APP`, it seems to work fine, it's listed with normal screen -ls, however there's a problem. If I want to check on the program, and try to reattach to the screen, after trying (and typing the password), the screen is terminated.

I don't have a problem with the password, the problem is that the reattached screen is terminating.
Has anyone any suggestions, how I could start the screen from bash with these conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`screen` is terminating because the program is terminating. If you want to see its output you can either log it (use `-L`) to examine the complete output afterwards, or, to see last few lines, start a shell with the screen and run your failing application from that shell. The screen won't exit until you exit the shell.

With `-L` screen will append to a logfile if it exists. You can also suggest a different filename than the default `screenlog.N` (N being the screen number) with `-Logfile` option.

**Upd:** probably the confusion was caused by running `screen` *inside* sudo session like `sudo screen`. In that case, screen is *run as root* (or other user if sudo was invoked with `-u` argument) and you need to run subsequent operations also as that user. For example, to reattach, `sudo screen -r`.

Comment: I think the program is terminating, because it is not started as root, so simply "sudo something" inside the command part of screen -dmS CMD doesn't really work.

Comment: Obviously, if you start screen under sudo, everything started within the screen also acquires the same privileges the sudo is giving. Anyway, by logging with -L you'll capture stdout and stderr into the log, so you'd find out. If you run `sudo screen bash` (or just `sudo screen`, since shell is run by default when there's no command), you can execute e.g. whoami and ps and see that yourself. But to reattach that screen you need to run `sudo screen -r` since the screen is running not as you but as that user,